# When to close the InputStream object used in the constructor of HSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, inputstream, hssfworkbook

I am working with `HSSFWorkbook` and I wanted to know where should I close the `InputStream` object that I have used while constructing the `HSSFWorkbook` object. Does HSSFWorkbook closes the stream in its constructor itself? or do we need to close it manually? And can we close it just after the constructor call? i.e., does `HSSFWorkbook` object use the `InputStream` object in its constructor only? or can it also use it in future (in this case we cant close it)? thank you.

```
public HSSFWorkbook loadSheet(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    return new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file)); 
}
```

Comment: It should be useful to share the respective code snippet.

Comment: @leopal Thanks for suggesting, I have added the code snippet. :-)

Comment: "Does HSSFWorkbook close the stream in its constructor" <- no, it does not.

Comment: It does, within the `POIFSFileSystem` class. And not only it does, the constructor of `POIFSFileSystem` clearly states that it does and what should be done in the rare cases that this is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `HSSFWorkbook` doesn't state whether the `InputStream` will be closed or left open, so at a first glance you shouldn't make assumptions that it's going to be closed. Digging deeper, however, the constructor of a class used within the constructor itself on the other hand does state clearly its behaviour.

At least in Apache POI 4.0.0 the call to `new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream)` will result in a call to `new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream)` which, in its implementation, does indeed appear to always close the stream and the constructor documentation confirms it.

This would seem to point to the following answers to your questions:

- Does `HSSFWorkbook` closes the stream in its constructor itself? Yes, indirectly.
- Or do we need to close it manually? Apparently not, unless they decide to no longer rely on `POIFSFileSystem`, which seems unlikely.
- And can we close it just after the constructor call? Apparently, yes... but there's no need for it.
- i.e. does `HSSFWorkbook` object use the `InputStream` object in its constructor only? Apparently so.

Comment: I like how the answer has been downvoted without providing any reason why and despite being carefully crafted against the sourcecode of the library itself in order to provide the most accurate answer possible. Smells like "retaliation" to an answer now deleted that I downvoted as it was proposing to write unnecessary code. I hope I'm wrong...

Comment: Thank you Filippo Possenti, I dont know why I am not being able to tag you, but your answer seems right, and hence I upvoted it too. Thanks for the clarification. ;-)